# Message Collector doesn't collect messages in DMs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So im trying to make a trivia command in direct message. But the bot doesn't collect the user's message. The bot DMs the user, Theres no error in the console, The bot supposed to log the message but it didn't.
here is the code that i use

```
    const channel = await message.author.createDM();
    const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000 }) // Wait 15 seconds
    collector.on('collect', msg => {
      console.log("Collected message: " + message.content);
      if (answers.includes(msg.content.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/\.|'|-|\s/g, ''))) {
        winner = msg.author;
        collector.stop();
      }
    });
    collector.on('end', () => {
      const answerEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Solo Trivia')
        .setFooter(message.member.displayName,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor(message.guild.me.displayHexColor);
      if (winner) 
        message.member.send(answerEmbed.setDescription(`Congratulations ${winner}, you gave the correct answer!`));
      else message.member.send(answerEmbed
        .setDescription(`Sorry ${message.member}, time's up! Better luck next time.`)
        .addField('Correct Answers', origAnswers.join('\n'))
      );
    });
```

Comment: In line 2 of your code you used a `filter`. Could you show us the code defining that filter, please?

Comment: const filter = m => !m.author.bot;

Comment: if you want i could show you the full code

Comment: I think that won't be needed. In line 3 you define `msg` but in line 4 (where to try to log the message) you are using `messsage.content` . You will need to change that to `msg.content`

Comment: Hmm that's not the case. Changed the `message.content` to `msg.content` and still the bot doesn't log the messages

Comment: In that case your full code could be useful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221950/discussion-between-n0te-and-veinify).